# Apache poi excel comments wrap text

Tags: java, excel, comments, apache-poi, word-wrap

How can I ensure that the comment holder will be big enough to show the comment? 
I've searched for some property like wrap text, but I had no luck.

```
if(drawingPatriarch == null)
{
    drawingPatriarch = sh.createDrawingPatriarch();
}

HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();

anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+1);
anchor.setRow1(row.getRowNum());
anchor.setRow2(row.getRowNum()+3);

Comment cellComment = drawingPatriarch.createCellComment(anchor);
cellComment.setString(new HSSFRichTextString(comment));
if(author != null)
    cellComment.setAuthor(author);

cell.setCellComment(cellComment);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

```
CellStyle wrapText=workbookWrite.createCellStyle();
wrapText.setWrapText(true);
cellComment.setCellStyle(wrapText);
```

Comment: `CellStyle` can be applied to cells `HSSFCell`. This method `setCellStyle` is not defined for `HSSFComment`.